# Password Encryption Using Spring Boot( using package org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder) Fails

Tags: spring-boot

Not able to Encrypt password even after writing the code correctly and importing the correct package, please find the code below for your reference.
Attached whole code for quick reference, please refer `register` method in the below code

Thank you

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.shameem.flightreservation.entities.User;
import com.shameem.flightreservation.repos.UserRepository;
import com.shameem.flightreservation.services.SecurityService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;


    private static final Logger LOGGER=LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/showReg")
    public String showRegistrationPage()
    {
        LOGGER.info("Inside showRegistrationPage()");
        return "Login/userRegistration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registerUser")
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
    {
        //LOGGER.info("Inside register()" + user);
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        LOGGER.info("After Encrypt Inside register()" + user);
        if(!(user.getEmail()==null))
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Login/login";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/showLogin")
    public String showLoginPage()
    {
        LOGGER.info("Inside showLoginPage()");
        return "Login/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam("email") String email,@RequestParam("password") String password,ModelMap modelMap)
    {
        //User user=userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        Boolean loginResponse=securityService.login(email, password);


        LOGGER.info("Inside login() and the email is: " + email);

        if(loginResponse)
        {
            return "findFlights";
        }

        else
        {
            modelMap.addAttribute("msg","Invalid user name or password");
        }
        return "Login/login";

    }

}
```

User Entity

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_role",joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password
                + "]";
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exact exception ?

Comment: @KedarJoshi there is no exception, the code is running fine but in the database, the password is saved as a normal text

Comment: .. then you need to check what exact values you are trying to save by putting a break point. It will also help a lot if you can add source code for `User` entity to your question.

Comment: @KedarJoshi `User` entity added. :)

Comment: Entity looks clean. Can you check the value of the password field right before and after you call `userRepository.save(user);`. ?

Comment: @KedarJoshi I don't know what exactly went wrong but it's working now. Thank you for your help:)